# Django is_active field is not changing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using `django 4.0` when i change the `is_active` to `False` from django admin,  it doesn't make any changes to the object, I have override the save method in models.

**models.py**

```
class Topic(CreatedModel, DatedModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        null=False,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        help_text="A unique field used for creating Topics in Kafka"
    )
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        choices=CATEGORY,
        help_text="Default for constant value updates"
    )
    selected_model = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        choices=ALERT_MODELS,
        unique=True,
        help_text="The Model for sending updates to Kafka"
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True
    )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            print("New object topic")
            topic_name = self.slug
            invoke_kafka_topic_create.delay(topic_name)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

**admin.py**

```
class TopicManager(admin.ModelAdmin):

   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if getattr(obj, 'created_by', None) is None:
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()
    else:
        obj.modified_by = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Can anyone advise ? The problem started when i added the `save()` in `models.py`

Comment: `super()` call is only running inside the `if` block. Unindent it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.save()` method should always call the super method, regardless whether `pk` is `None` or not, so:

```
class Topic(CreatedModel, DatedModel):
    # …
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            print('New object topic')
            invoke_kafka_topic_create.delay(self.slug)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)  # 🖘 outside if body
```

Answer (score 1):

As we know, `save` method is called when we create or update any object of Django.
If you add
`if self.pk is None:` this function will not be get called on object update.